# C++ Builder STL for OS X fails?

Tags: stl, c++builder, firemonkey

Has anybody tried something as simple as `#include <vector>` in an application for the Mac compiled with XE2?

Is something so basic broken in XE2 update 1 for C++ Builder or is my install broken?

Simply adding `#include <vector>` to a new fire monkey HD app, I get build failures:

```
[BCC32 Error] cstdlib(43): E2015 Ambiguity between 'ldiv_t' and 'Posix::Stdlib::ldiv_t'
  Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(7): #include C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\boost_1_39\boost\tr1\tr1\vector
     vector(16): #include C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\boost_1_39\boost/tr1/detail/config_all.hpp
    config_all.hpp(48): #include c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\include\dinkumware\cstdlib
    cstdlib(32): namespace std
```

From the code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include <vector>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
   : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from Embarcadero (this is for update 2 only):

- Open cstdlib in the [RADStudioXE2]\include\dinkumware directory
- Take line 49: `using _CSTD size_t; using _CSTD div_t; using _CSTD ldiv_t;`
- Move it above the "#if defined" block right above it (line 33)

The STL can now be compiled into an FMX C++ application

Answer (score 0):

try removing $(CG_BOOST_ROOT) from your include paths.

Comment: Thanks Dean, but this made no difference, build still fails in cstdlib.

Comment: what's the new error? there shouldn't be any reference to C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\boost_1_39\boost\tr1\tr1\vector if you've cleaned out your include paths.

Comment: The error is identical, in cstdlib.  Quick tests show including <memory> also produces the same result. And wouldn't removing the boost include path mean I could not use boost in my OS X apps?

Comment: Removing boost is just the first step in determining where the conflict is. The order of the paths can usually be rearranged to work around the conflict. Another place to look is the bccosx.cfg file. It's probably faster to copy the command line passed to bccosx, and work with it on in a shell until you narrow down which include paths are causing problems, and the rearrange them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint.  I'll play with the command line and post here.

Comment: Dean. thanks got the solution above after filing with Embarcadero.